# How to combine pandas, dataclasses to import data

Tags: python, pandas, oop, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to learn classes with dataclasses

```
@dataclass
class Collect:
    url : str
    def collect(url):    
        df = pd.read_csv(url)
        return df
df = Collect("national_news_scrape.csv")
df.head()
```

But I get error:

AttributeError: 'Collect' object has no attribute 'head'

Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause

You are getting the `AttributeError` because your code constructs the `Collect` object with `Collect("national_news_scrape.csv")`, *but* does not then call the `collect()` method to return a pandas `DataFrame`.

The `head()` method is defined on a `DataFrame` instance and not an instance of your `Collect` class.

#### The fix

I do however sense some confusion! I will assume that your code is a *Minimal (non-)Working Example*, which would explain why you are using `@dataclass` here when it doesn't seem necessary.

Danila has posted some working code, though I haven't tested it myself - please consult this answer for a correction.

*Additionally*, please note the change in signature of the `collect()` method - it now no longer requires a `url` positional argument because it uses the `self.url` instance attribute that is set by the constructor from `@dataclasss`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
@dataclass
class Collect:
    url: str

    def collect(self):    
        df = pd.read_csv(self.url)
        return df

# create an instance of Collect class
instance = Collect("national_news_scrape.csv")
print(instance.url)  #  national_news_scrape.csv

# call the method of Collect class
df = instance.collect()
print(df.head())
```